# Java int from textfield

Tags: java, javafx, calculator

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to get an int from a textfield for my calculator in JavaFX. I have 2 textfields where people can write a number:

```
hb.getChildren().addAll(label1, textField);
textField.getText();
hb.setSpacing(10);
hb.getChildren().addAll(label2, textField2);
textField2.getText();
hb.setSpacing(10);
```

So this is what I made to get an int from a textfield but it doesnt work:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
int y = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I saw on internet people used event but I'm not sure if in this case I have to use it.

Error log:

```
 Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at test.start(test.java:57)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more Exception running application test
```

I hope someone can help me,

Thomas

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Explain the "it doesn't work" part. The call to `textField.getText();` in the first part is not necessary.

Comment: You need to put the `int y = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());` inside a button action. If you call it before you can't be sure that the user was even able to input something

Comment: why do you call in the first block ```textField.getText();```? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: You should watch more tutorials or get a book like Head First Java. Because your code does not make proper sense. Also post the error log. I do not sell Head First Java.

Comment: I added the error log

Comment: Your `TextField` is empty, and an empty String does not contain a "parsable integer" as said in the documentation of `Integer#parseInt(String s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw on internet people used event but I'm not sure if in this case I have to use it.

`TextField` contains the empty string by default. If you do not use some kind of event or a listener to the `text` property you do not get a value that the user may enter into the field.

In this case I recommend using a `TextFormatter` to make things simpler:

```
TextField tf1 = new TextField();
TextField tf2 = new TextField();

StringConverter<Integer> converter = new IntegerStringConverter();

TextFormatter<Integer> formatter1 = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0);
TextFormatter<Integer> formatter2 = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0);

tf1.setTextFormatter(formatter1);
tf2.setTextFormatter(formatter2);

Label sum = new Label();
sum.textProperty().bind(IntegerExpression.integerExpression(formatter1.valueProperty())
        .add(IntegerExpression.integerExpression(formatter2.valueProperty())).asString("Sum: %d"));

VBox root = new VBox(tf1, tf2, sum);
```

You could simply use

```
int x = formatter1.getValue();
int y = formatter1.getValue();
```

if you don't want the binding. The formatter prevents the user from leaving invalid data in the field and takes care of updating it's `value` property when the user leaves the field or presses enter.

Answer (score -1):

sir the problem is your trying to convert an empty string to integer as the error show :

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

to prevent such thing you can add this to your code

```
int x,y;
try{
     x = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().trim());
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    x = 0;
}
try{
     y = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText().trim());
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    y = 0;
}
```